# Want this all result in a single SQL Server query

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
select 
    OrgId, COUNT(*), SUM(Amount)
from  
    InvoiceDetail 
where 
    InvoiceSubDt between '2018-05-14 06:30:00.000' and '2018-05-14 08:30:00.000' 
    and Ischecked in (0, 1, 2) 
    and Paymentstatus not in ('E003-Duplicate Txn-ref Number', 'E009-Invalid Cardnumber')
group by
    OrgId


select 
    OrgId, COUNT(*), SUM(Amount)
from 
    InvoiceDetail 
where 
    InvoiceApproveDt between '2018-05-14 06:30:00.000' and '2018-05-14 08:30:00.000' 
    and Ischecked in (1) 
    and Paymentstatus not in ('E003-Duplicate Txn-ref Number',
                              'E009-Invalid Cardnumber',
                              'Pending', 'Rejected', 'Payment Returned')
group by 
    OrgId

select 
    OrgId, COUNT(*), SUM(Amount)
from 
    InvoiceDetail 
where 
    InvoiceApproveDt between '2018-05-14 06:30:00.000' and '2018-05-14 08:30:00.000' 
    and Ischecked in (0) 
    and Paymentstatus not in ('E003-Duplicate Txn-ref Number', 'E009-Invalid Cardnumber', 'Pending', 'Card Debited')
group by
    OrgId

select 
    OrgId, COUNT(*), SUM(Amount)
from 
    InvoiceDetail 
where 
    Utrdatetime between '2018-05-14 06:30:00.000' and '2018-05-14 08:30:00.000' 
    and Ischecked in (1) 
    and Paymentstatus not in ('E003-Duplicate Txn-ref Number', 'E009-Invalid Cardnumber', 'Pending', 'Card Debited', 'Payment Returned') 
    and UTR != 'NA'
group by 
    OrgId
```

What I tried is but it is giving me half result

```
select OrgId, SUm(Amount),
       sum(Case when Ischecked in (0,1,2) and Paymentstatus NOT in ('E003-Duplicate Txn-ref Number','E009-Invalid Cardnumber') then 1  else 0 end) as 'one',
       sum(Case when Ischecked in (1) and Paymentstatus NOT in ('E003-Duplicate Txn-ref Number','E009-Invalid Cardnumber','Pending','Rejected','Payment Returned') then 1 else 0 end) as 'two',
       sum(Case when Ischecked in (0) and Paymentstatus NOT in ('E003-Duplicate Txn-ref Number','E009-Invalid Cardnumber','Pending','Card Debited') then 1 else 0 end) as 'three',
       SUM(Case when Utrdatetime between '2018-05-14 06:30:00.000' and '2018-05-14 08:30:00.000' and Ischecked in (1) and Paymentstatus NOT in ('E003-Duplicate Txn-ref Number','E009-Invalid Cardnumber','Pending','Card Debited',
'Payment Returned') and UTR!='NA' then 1 else 0 end) as 'four'
from InvoiceDetail
where InvoiceSubDt between '2018-05-14 06:30:00.000' and '2018-05-14 08:30:00.000' 
group by OrgId;
```

How I want the Result to be is

```
Orgid  Count_Approved  Amount  Count_Declined  Amount      Count_Pending  AT
25           2            65463           12        6546        121       85
12          12            87412           12       56           1         854
100         72            651132          2         4654        2         215
```

Comment: I think what you want is `UNION ALL`

Comment: what do you mean by `half result` ? Please show your current output and the expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the half that is working are the counters, while you still need every separate sum.

To get the sums you just have to add them conditionally, exactly the same way you got the counters:

```
select OrgId, 

       sum(Case when Ischecked in (0,1,2) and Paymentstatus NOT in ('E003-Duplicate Txn-ref Number','E009-Invalid Cardnumber') then Amount  else 0 end) as 'SumOne',
       sum(Case when Ischecked in (1) and Paymentstatus NOT in ('E003-Duplicate Txn-ref Number','E009-Invalid Cardnumber','Pending','Rejected','Payment Returned') then Amount else 0 end) as 'SumTwo',
       sum(Case when Ischecked in (0) and Paymentstatus NOT in ('E003-Duplicate Txn-ref Number','E009-Invalid Cardnumber','Pending','Card Debited') then Amount else 0 end) as 'SumThree',
       SUM(Case when Utrdatetime between '2018-05-14 06:30:00.000' and '2018-05-14 08:30:00.000' and 
                     Ischecked in (1) and Paymentstatus NOT in ('E003-Duplicate Txn-ref Number','E009-Invalid Cardnumber','Pending','Card Debited', 'Payment Returned') and UTR!='NA' then Amount else 0 end) as 'SumFour'

       sum(Case when Ischecked in (0,1,2) and Paymentstatus NOT in ('E003-Duplicate Txn-ref Number','E009-Invalid Cardnumber') then 1  else 0 end) as 'CountOne',
       sum(Case when Ischecked in (1) and Paymentstatus NOT in ('E003-Duplicate Txn-ref Number','E009-Invalid Cardnumber','Pending','Rejected','Payment Returned') then 1 else 0 end) as 'CountTwo',
       sum(Case when Ischecked in (0) and Paymentstatus NOT in ('E003-Duplicate Txn-ref Number','E009-Invalid Cardnumber','Pending','Card Debited') then 1 else 0 end) as 'CountThree',
       SUM(Case when Utrdatetime between '2018-05-14 06:30:00.000' and '2018-05-14 08:30:00.000' and 
                     Ischecked in (1) and Paymentstatus NOT in ('E003-Duplicate Txn-ref Number','E009-Invalid Cardnumber','Pending','Card Debited', 'Payment Returned') and UTR!='NA' then 1 else 0 end) as 'CountFour'

from InvoiceDetail
where InvoiceSubDt between '2018-05-14 06:30:00.000' and '2018-05-14 08:30:00.000' 
group by OrgId;
```